# Sprites and text size

Tags: html, css

[image: Text making line]

---

I've created a sprite at a website I'm using to learn CSS at http://flexibletheme.tumblr.com/, however since the width is set at 24px the text tries to make a small vertical column.

Anyway to get it to render normally with 24px of margin on the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ditch the width:24px; add padding-left:24px

Comment: I decided to remake the sprite to make it all vertical, so I could use this (before it was 2 across and continuing down). The <span> method discussed above was the other option.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your sprite inside of a nested `<span>` instead of wrapping it around your link text. Like this:

```
<a href="#"><span class="sprite"></span>Sample Link</a>
```

Be sure to either float your sprite to the left or make it `display:inline-block;` so that it can retain a width and height but still be inline with your link text.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the  element around your sidebar unordered list and children instead of closing it before it does anything:

```
<aside>
   <ul>
      <li>stuff</li>
   </ul>
</aside>
```

Then give it a width, or let content and sidebar float and clear them after. (I'd also recommend looking into stuff like grids for ease.. http://978.gs/)

Answer (score 0):

write this `white-space: nowrap;` in your `a` tag

```
#links li a{white-space: nowrap;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If IE7 support (and below) is not an issue, you could use `:before` pseudo element without adding any extra mark-up:

```
#links a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 30px;
    min-height: 20px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
#links a:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 2px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url(http://static.tumblr.com/wgijwsy/itFlt1l8x/links.png);
}
a#rss:before { background-position: -24px 0 }
a#facebook:before { background-position: 0 -24px }
a#twitter:before { background-position: 0 -48px }
```

Otherwise, add `span` inside the anchors and replace `a:before` with `a span.icon`.

And move the `h2` outside of your `ul`. That's [invalid HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html).